# Is it clear in the following sentence the distinction between the "individual" and the "whole"?

Tags: meaning, writing

Is it clear in the following sentence the distinction between the "individual" (a single person), and the "whole" (nature, universe...everything around, etc)?

"People want to be eternal as an individual because they forgot how to be eternal as a whole."

I wrote that as an indirect way of saying: People created the soul to be eternal because they forgot that they were already eternal with nature, the universe.

Comment: I highly doubt this sentence makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it seems clear enough to me (assuming that the sentence occurs in some sort of context), but I might say

> People want to be eternal *as individuals* because they *have forgotten* how to be eternal as a whole.

I changed *individual* to *individuals* so that it agrees with *people*, and changed *forgot* to *have forgotten* because it places the emphasis on the result (i.e. they don't remember anymore) rather than the event at which the forgetting took place (see [uses of the present perfect simple](http://www.ego4u.com/en/cram-up/grammar/present-perfect-simple)).

If the sentence is meant to be read without any context, then it would probably be hard to understand your intended meaning. However, your explanation

> People created the soul to be eternal because they forgot that they were already eternal with nature, the universe.

seems to get this point across quite well.

Comment: It is part of a dialogue in a short story I wrote called "The Girl without a Soul" (http://alexandrochen.com/existential-fiction/the-girl-without-a-soul/). I'm not sure if the context is enough but well, I not planning to make it that explicit.

Comment: @janoChen: I see. Well, it looks like you might be keeping it vague on purpose so people have to think about the meaning a little bit (e.g. neither of the people in the conversation appear to understand what it means). I suppose that I am getting off topic now and heading towards lit. crit., though, so I'll cut myself off.